# How to create effective experiences/emotion to change punctured tyres for a car?

Tags: usability, physical, experience

Keeping climate, location and gender into consideration, the mechanism of changing punctured tyres have not seen greater changes? Still it takes energy,effort and time, moreover awful experience around it! Cars & Passengers are interlinked by aesthetics, dashboard and comfort. But what has been done to core problem areas when you are stuck in a cyclone and mending a car tyre with high turn-around time to fix -Is'nt that a strategical experience point for businesses? Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly there are great tools to accelerate the process, but those are not suitable to take with you in the car. If you also consider that the wheels have to be securely attached to the structure, there are not many options.

Although, there are some patents for products not commercialized yet or for systems like the ones in use for race cars, those involve traction or locking instead of pure friction. But those are complex and expensive mechanisms that are not available for your average car.

It will be great to have something like the quick release of bicycles, but it seems far in the futures for most cars.

And situations like the one you mention are not common for the majority of users, so it's not specially interesting, even as an option. How much extra would you pay for a system that lets you change the tire in a short time instead of the actual normal time and effort?

Also, even if you consider punctured tires, they happen less and less, so for the very few occasions that it happens, it doesn't look to be worth the money invested in solving the situation from the rim perspective.

But, there are some interesting works with the tire itself, to make it self repair and to deflate more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

There actually have been made changes over the last years. In my new car (as of 2010) there were no spare tyre, just a tyre inflator. I'm still looking suspicious at it while taking the car for a longer spin, but it works (I'm told).

Works in a few seconds and you don't have to change tyres, getting dirty and oily, saying things to the surroundings you later regret. Just inflate - and drive to the nearest tyre shop.

[image]

*Tyre Inflator*